# Looking for a tool to convert flattened CSV into XSD

Tags: xml, csv, xsd

I have an Excel (or CSV) file that contains the following "flattened" columns:

```
ID,XPath,Required?,BaseType,Restrictions
```

For example:

```
A1,/Foo[]/@baz,Optional,INTEGER,Max=4000000000 Min=0 Pattern={[\-+]?[0-9]+}
```

I *think* all the elements are there to basically re-create the XSD, correct?

Does a tool already exist that will do this?  If so, could I get a pointer? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Makes one wonder, how was that Excel populated to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No out of box library exists for this. You need to create your own solution. Since XSD is XML it self, the generation is not the problem but the problem is parsing the XPath expression and identifying the hierarchy that need to be created.

Comment: I was afraid of that. :(